# bash - wildcards in file list

Tags: bash, loops, wildcard

So I have a bunch of measurements for a varying parameter `T` from different clients. The files are stored in `${LOGDIR}` and adhere to the following naming pattern:

```
${LOGDIR}/client<id>/client_<id>_blahblah_T=<param_value>_rep=<rep_no>.log
```

I now want to select all clients' files for a fixed `T,rep`

```
for rep in {1..5}
do
    outfile=${OUTDIR}/"aux_rep${rep}.dat"
    for T in {1..64}
    do
        files="${LOGDIR}/log_client"*"/client"*"_T=C=${T}_rep=${rep}.log"
        echo "new iteration"
        printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
    done
done
```

this gets me exactly one output per iteration:

```
new iteration
/home/.../log_client*/client*_T=<param_value>_rep=<rep_no>.log
```

Now obviously, I would have liked these `*` to have been resolved.

And I'm a bit surprised because I've used

```
files="${LOGDIR}/${prefix}"*"${interm}"*"${ext}"
```

in other scripts successfully (although that was not within a loop and all files were in the same directory).

How do I get `files` to list the correct data files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not declaring and populating `files` array:

```
files="${LOGDIR}/log_client"*"/client"*"_T=C=${T}_rep=${rep}.log"
```

It should be changed to this to populate `files` array:

```
files=( "${LOGDIR}/log_client"*"/client"*"_T=C=${T}_rep=${rep}.log" )
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. But then why was there no issue with ``files="${LOGDIR}/${prefix}"*"${interm}"*"${ext}"`` when all files were in the same directory?

Comment: That will not expand the globs and won't make `files` an array with expanded matching file names.

Comment: Strangely enough, it did. Anyway, it's not important, now that you posted the correct way of doing this. Was just wondering.